# Recurrence with logs T(n) = T(logn)+log(log(n))

Tags: algorithm, substitution, recurrence, proof, induction

How to find  T(n)=Θ(f(n)) for the recurrence T(n) = T(logn)+log(log(n))?

I think T(n)= Θ(log(n)) but the proof is the hard part for me. I'm going to attempt to prove by substitution but please help me with that. I also tried a proof by induction but that got out of hand quickly...

Assume T(n) = logn such that

proof of big o:

```
T(n+1) = T(log(n+1))+loglog(n+1)
       = loglog(n+1) + loglog(n+1) < c*log(n) (check)
```

proof of big ohmega:

```
T(n-1) = T(log(n-1))+loglog(n-1)
       = loglog(n-1) + loglog(n-1) > c*log(n) (not good)
```

Thoughts on proving this via sub. or via induction? ... wish I could just plug and chug into master theorem ~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct approach seems the best fit.

```
T (n) = log log n + T (log n) =
        log log n + log log log n + T (log log n) =
        log log n + log log log n + log log log log n + T (log log log n) =
        log log n + log log log n + log log log log n + log log log log log n + ...
```

The first term is `log log n`, and every term dominates the next one.
So the function is Omega (log log n).

Comment: Oh snap good point! okay so then by sub. we can say c*logloglogn + loglogn >= c*loglogn for the upperbound (are we sure here) b/c in the lower bound we would get it to work as  c*logloglogn + loglogn <= c*loglogn (check)

Comment: Perhaps `0 <= log f (x) <= 0.5 f (x)` will help in formally showing that the first term directly dominates the whole series.

Comment: Ok I guess I'll keep digging but thanks for the correction of logn -> loglogn,  I definitely agree!